# Write function to apply to pandas data frame which looks at row on question and row above

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, as below:

```
Start       End
2017-12-21  2017-12-23
2018-01-01  2018-01-05
2018-01-04  2018-01-07
2018-03-05  2018-09-06
```

I would like to write a function that checks if the value in Start is between the value of Start and End in the row above, and sets OverlapWithAboveRow to be 1 or 0 accordingly.

```
Start       End         OverlapWithAboveRow
2017-12-21  2017-12-23  0
2018-01-01  2018-01-05  0
2018-01-04  2018-01-07  1
2018-03-05  2018-09-06  0
```

How would I do this? Is it possible to write a function to use in the apply method that references the values of a row and the one above it as well?

I know it would be possible to do with a for loop, but it's fairly slow and I think there probably is a quicker way.

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[i-1,'Start'] <= df.loc[i,'Start'] <= df.loc[i-1,'End']:
        df.loc[i,'OverlapWithAboveRow'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a loop you can you use [pd.Series.between](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) with `shift` to return a boolean series and specify the type as `int` then set it to the new column name.

```
df['OverlapWithAboveRow'] = df['Start'].between(df['Start'].shift(), df['End'].shift()).astype(int)

       Start        End     OverlapWithAboveRow
0   2017-12-21  2017-12-23       0
1   2018-01-01  2018-01-05       0
2   2018-01-04  2018-01-07       1
3   2018-03-05  2018-09-06       0
```

If you did want to create a function you can:

```
def myFunc(df, start, end):
    """
    df is the dataframe
    start is the name of the column for the start times
    end is the name of the column for the end times
    """
    return df[start].between(df[start].shift(), df[end].shift()).astype(int)

df['OverlapWithAboveRow'] = myFunc(df, 'Start', 'End')
```